# How to migrate this mutlipart file upload to Spring Boot 2.4?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, multipartform-data, http-request-parameters

With Spring Boot 2.3 I was using the following Kotlin code

```
val mvcResultImage = this.mockMvc!!.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/somepath)
        .file("files[]", imageFile.getBytes())
        .characterEncoding("UTF-8"))
        .andReturn()
```

in an integration test for a controller with a function

```
@PostMapping(path = ["/somepath"],
    consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE],
    produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
@ResponseBody
fun createFromBytes(@RequestParam("files[]") file: MultipartFile): ResponseEntity<Any> {
   ...
}
```

In 2.3 I was able to handle the request in the controller function whereas in 2.4 the controller function raises a `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException` with the message `Required request part 'files[]' is not present` and causes HTTP response code 400.

I don't find anything in the migration guide and list of handled issues for this version change.

A rename to `file` in both controller and request doesn't help, I don't remember why I added `[]` in the code working with 2.3, but I think it was necessary to make it work.

I'm using Spring Boot through the maven parent mechanism with `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a known issues in Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26261) coming from Spring. It's fixed in Spring Boot 2.4.2. The linked issue contains a successfully tested workaround in case you're stuck with 2.4.1: Create `MockMultipartFile` with `MockMultipartFile( String name, @Nullable String originalFilename, @Nullable String contentType, @Nullable byte[] content)` (specification of `originalFilename` matters).